# Getting SmscManagement is not registered error in smsc gateway management UI

Tags: jboss, sms-gateway, smpp, restcomm, ss7

I am using Telestax Restcomm smsc gateway 7.2.109.
When I load sms gateway management UI, I am getting

15:31:12:520 [ERROR] javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : org.mobicents.smsc:layer=SmscPropertiesManagement,name=SmscManagement is not registered.. (Full Stack Trace)

Also I am getting following errors while starting smsc server (jboss).

08:56:25,851 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean SCTPManagement
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="SCTPManagement",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,858 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean SCTPShellExecutor
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="SCTPShellExecutor",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,865 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean RoutingLabelFormat
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="RoutingLabelFormat",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,874 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean Mtp3UserPart
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="Mtp3UserPart",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,882 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean M3UAShellExecutor
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="M3UAShellExecutor",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,889 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean SS7Clock
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="SS7Clock",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,899 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean SS7Scheduler
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="SS7Scheduler",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,907 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean SccpStack
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="SccpStack",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,914 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean SccpExecutor
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="SccpExecutor",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,921 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean TcapStack
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="TcapStack",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,927 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean TcapExecutor
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="TcapExecutor",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,934 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean ShellExecutor
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="ShellExecutor",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,940 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean MapStack
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="MapStack",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,950 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean MAPSS7Service
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="MAPSS7Service",type=Component already registered.

08:56:25,984 WARN  [AbstractDeploymentContext] (main) Unable to register deployment mbean Ss7Management
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: jboss.deployment:id="Ss7Management",type=Component already registered.

**08:56:26,041 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] (main) Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/home/telestax/Downloads/restcomm-smsc-7.2.109/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/restcomm-smsc-server/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: SCTPManagement**

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "vfszip:/home/telestax/Downloads/restcomm-smsc-7.2.109/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/smpp-server-ra-du-7.0.5.jar/" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "SmppManagement" (should be in state "Real", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'SmppManagement' **")
  Deployment "vfszip:/home/telestax/Downloads/restcomm-smsc-7.2.109/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/smsc-resource-adaptors-du-7.2.109.jar/" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "SmscManagement" (should be in state "Real", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'SmscManagement' **")
  Deployment "vfszip:/home/telestax/Downloads/restcomm-smsc-7.2.109/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/smsc-services-du-7.2.109.jar/" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "SmscManagement" (should be in state "Real", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'SmscManagement' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/home/telestax/Downloads/restcomm-smsc-7.2.109/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/restcomm-smsc-server/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: SCTPManagement is already installed.
  Deployment "SmscManagement" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'SmscManagement' **
  Deployment "SmppManagement" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'SmppManagement' **

Kindly help.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Server is working fine now.

Getting below error when calling from smtp simulator client.

14:26:41,913 INFO  [SmppServerConnector] (SmppManagement) New channel from [172.17.0.1:57210]
14:26:41,916 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.17.0.1:57210) received PDU: (bind_transmitter: 0x00000023 0x00000002 0x00000000 0x00000001) (body: systemId [test] password [test] systemType [] interfaceVersion [0x34] addressRange (0x01 0x01 [6666])) (opts: )
14:26:41,917 ERROR [DefaultSmppServerHandler] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.17.0.1:57210) Received BIND request but no ESME configured for SystemId=test Host=172.17.0.1 Port=57210 SmppBindType=TRANSMITTER
14:26:41,918 WARN  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.17.0.1:57210) Bind request rejected or failed for connection [172.17.0.1:57210] with error [SMPP processing error [0x0000000F]]
14:26:41,918 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.17.0.1:57210) send PDU: (bind_transmitter_resp: 0x0000001A 0x80000002 0x0000000F 0x00000001 result: "System ID invalid") (body: systemId [test]) (opts: (sc_interface_version: 0x0210 0x0001 [34]))
14:26:41,919 INFO  [UnboundSmppSession] (SmppManagement.UnboundSession.172.17.0.1:57210) Connection closed with [172.17.0.1:57210]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you retry from the latest snapshot release from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestComm-SMSC/ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot jean. The server is getting started without any errors now.

Now I am facing issue when calling the server from smtp simulator.  Getting below error at server side.  Kindly help.

Comment: Did you created the ESME in the SMSC Management console for system type/systemId `test` ?

Comment: Yes. ESME Name:test,   system id:test,   password:test, IP address:127.0.0.1,  port: 2776, smpp bind type: "receiver",  smpp session type: "server".   All other fields have been left to default.   As you asked, system type is blank.

Comment: Working fine after modifying smpp bind type as transceiver from receiver. Thanks a lot.